# what's the ratio of area of triangle AEB to the area of quadrilateral AGIB?

Tags: geometry

> in the figure below , $ABC$ is a right triangle in $C$  , $AI$ , $BG$ are bisectors of of angles $A$ and $B$ respectively,  what's the ratio of  area of triangle $AEB$ to the area of  quadrilateral $AGIB$ ?

[image]

I need a hint to go , can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Specifically for the given coordinates (I assume that $A=(9,0)$) or in the general case?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  general case , i Will edit the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E$ is the centre of the incircle, whose radius is $r$.
Then the area of $AEB$ is $$\frac 12cr.$$
It is well-known that  $r=\frac{ab}{a+b+c}$.
As bisectors partition in the proportion of the adjacent sides, we have $CG:GA=a:c$ and $CI:IB=b:c$, hence the area of $CGI$ is
$$ \frac12 \frac{ab}{b+c}\frac{ba}{a+c}.$$
The desired proportion is therefore
$$ \frac{AEB}{AGIB}=\frac{\frac12\frac{abc}{a+b+c}}{\frac12ab-\frac12\frac{(ab)^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}}=\frac{ab+ac+bc+c^2}{a^2+2ab+2ac+b^2+2bc+c^2}=\frac12.$$

Comment: I know it's standard, but a small note at the beginning saying that $a = BC, b = AC$ and $c = AB$ would probably improve readability. It took me a couple of seconds to figure out what the $c$ in $\frac12cr$ was.